# Unable to open a new fragment on Itemclicklistener in listview

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I cant open a new fragment  on Itemclicklistener in listview with this code. How do I solve this problem?

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
   if (position == 0) {

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    menu = new Menu();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.frag, menu);
    ft.commit();
```

Comment: What does "cant open" mean? Have you debugged your code? Can you confirm your click listener is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Below code is work for me. Try it. If you need any clarification ask.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {       
                Fragment fr = new Menu2(); // next fragment class name is Menu2. Change it to your next class name
                FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();                   
                ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fr); // your main layout id. not next fragment layout.
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
```

Comment: That doesnt work for me and my main layout id is frag.

Comment: then problem is in your layout, android manifest or project settings. better if you check that layout 1st. jave code has no error.